# Restygwt download byte[]

Tags: gwt, resty-gwt

I have only an array of byte on the client side. 
Another server send me JSON

```
{
 report - byte[]
}
```

I am looking for ways to save byte [] in browser

Send them to server or I can download from client side.

I can not find any solution at all.

So my question "Is it possible to save with restygwt byte [] an how???"

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to save the file directly from Resty.

https://github.com/resty-gwt/resty-gwt/issues/341

The most common workarounds to download files using AJAX are not using AJAX at all.

- You can simply change the URL (using window.location) or (using javascript) create or;
- create a form (using JS) and post that form.

In my projects, I simple create a URL to my REST endpoint attaching any query parameters needed and use it as the href to a link.

For instance, if your RestyGwt endpoint points to /entity/1/bytes
just do

```
new Anchor("Download", "/entity/1/bytes");
```

your endpoint must produce a downloadable file type say:

```
@Produces("text/txt")
```